# Delphi - Use Indy to login and dowload files using cookies

Tags: delphi, cookies, authentication, indy

I need use Indy (v10) on my XE3 to make this:

1. List item
2. login to webpage "A" by username and password;
3. capture cookies sent by webpage after login;
4. load a new webpage "B" using cookies (in fact I can access on this webpage only after login);
5. find all files link from webpage "B" by parse html code;
6. download all the files;

My problems are:

1. I don't know how make the login;
2. I don't know how capture and using cookie to access on webpage "B";
3. I don't know how use the cookie to download the files;

Is it possible have a piece of code about these points? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer can get you up to speed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12723859/800214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The login is usually done as a post to a page, but there's no laws or standards here, so you have to analyze the login page and check how it works. Remember that anything done in the browser can be mimicked with INDY, but you first have to know how the particular page you want works.
2. INDY manages cookies for you, just assign a TIdCookieManager instance to your HTTP object.
3. The same as point 2, just use the same HTTP/CookieManager objects and this will be transparent to you.

No code, really, as per the point 1.

Comment: So if I use TIdCookieManager (and TIdHttp) this retrieve the cookie for me after the login and send it when I try to access on new webpage, is right?

Comment: Yes, as long as the new webpage belongs to the domain/sub-domain(s) defined in the cookie, that's right.