# Why do I get the login page when I try to log in to Craigslist?

Tags: delphi, indy, craigslist

I am trying to log in to Craigslist using Delphi 2010 and latest version of Indy 10, and retrieve my account page (in order to gather a listing of all my posts).

However, when I post the login details, [the returned HTML](http://chopapp.com/#zg9e3pre) is [that of the login page](https://accounts.craigslist.org/login), whereas I expect to get [my account page listing my postings](http://chopapp.com/#oi7e50u9).

Here is my latest code:

```
function TfrmMain.Login: string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Request: TStringList;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Request := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Request.Add('op=login');
        Request.Add('redirect=http://www.craigslist.org/');
        Request.Add('login=' + edtEmail.Text);
        Request.Add('password=' + edtPassword.Text);
        IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
          try
            SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
            SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;

            IdHTTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
            IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
            IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
            IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            IdHTTP.Post('https://accounts.craigslist.org/login', Request, Response);
            Result := IdHTTP.Get('https://accounts.craigslist.org/');
          finally
            SSLHandler.Free;
          end;
        finally
          IdHTTP.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Request.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

I have confirmed through debugging that the email and password are correct values as they are passed in the request parameters, so why don't I get the page I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the HTML you receive, the name of the login field is `inputEmailHandle`, not `login`. Likewise, the password field is `inputPassword`, not `password`. There are also some additional fields that you omit, including `step`, `rt`, and `rp`. I see no `op` or `redirect` fields in the form.

In other words, the code shown here is not code for logging in to Craigslist; it's [code for logging in to Filestrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723859/33732) with the addresses changed around, without regard for the significance of the surrounding code.